# Why is an "L" getting added to my Java path?

Tags: java, jar

I have a jar loaded in my classpath (in iReport if it matters) that I am certain has the desired method yet when I try to test the connection, thus calling the jar, I get a java.lang.NoSuchMethodError, saying it is referencing the class

```
Lorg/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext
```

I'm not sure if this is related to the problem or not but where did the 'L' at the beginning come from? Another time I was referencing a class there was a 'V' after the class. Where are these letters coming from and what do they mean?

Start of the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:  
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader
.getCurrentWebApplicationContext()Lorg/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext;
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

These letters are used by Java to encode the method signature internally. E.g., an "L" announces a following "Object", which is specified by its full class name and followed by a semicolon. The "V" should have been preceeded by parentheses and describes a return type of "void".

Take your example:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader
>   .getCurrentWebApplicationContext()Lorg/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext;

It says, that there is no method in class `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader` called `getCurrentWebApplicationContext` that accepts no arguments [denoted by `()`] and returns an object (announced by `L`) called `org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext (closed by ';').

**EDIT:** The list of all codes is in Table 3.2 of the [JNI specs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html#wp276).

**EDIT2:** Even more authoritive: section [4.3 Descriptors](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#1169) of the JVM specification contains a complete reference of the format and codes.

Comment: Is there a good reference for the letter codes? I was going to post essentially the same answer, but I didn't want to make unsubstantiated statements.

Answer (score 10):

The `L` character is used to signify a classname in Java's internal class specification.

See the [Java VM spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#14894) for details.

And a [table](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#84645) of the field types:

```
BaseType
B     byte (signed byte)
C     char (Unicode character)
D     double (double-precision floating-point value)
F     float (single-precision floating-point value)
I     int (integer)
J     long (long integer)
L<classname>;     reference (an instance of class <classname>)
S     short (signed short)
Z     boolean (true or false)
[     reference (one array dimension )
```

Comment: I also found that: 


P   - project

F   -  folder