# I'm getting a NoSuchMethodError exception in my application. But where is the "L" getting appended infront of "com/test/.."

Tags: java, exception, nosuchmethoderror

Execution exception
NoSuchMethodError occured : com.test.refFilesDataService.service.RefFilesDataServiceDelegate.fetchSegmentation(Lcom/test/refFilesDataService/service/RefFilesDataServiceSegmentationRequest;)Lcom/test/refFilesDataService/service/RefFilesDataServiceSegmentationResponse;

Calling using the following line:

RefFilesDataServiceSegmentationResponse response = getService()
                    .fetchSegmentation(request);

This is a newly added method to the external jar I'm referring to. All other methods in the jar works without a problem except this. Works in my local but fails in the Dev environment

Comment: Duplicate?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509943/why-is-an-l-getting-added-to-my-java-path

Comment: Correct its Duplicate. Thanks.

Comment: But still I dont know why this doesnt work when its already there in the jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

javap -classpath yourexternal.jar com.test.refFilesDataService.service.RefFilesDataServiceDelegate

on your test & dev environment and compare the method & signatures.

javap documentation available at

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html